# codeigniter mod rewrite 301 redirect old to new domain, gives 404 error

Tags: codeigniter

I'm trying to redirect old to new domain, both are pointing to same host.

```
RewriteRule ^http://www.firstdomain.some/page.php?query1=q$ http://seconddomain.some/etc/ [L,R=301]
```

This is not working, when it's having a query to redirect from .

I i try .

```
RewriteRule ^http://www.firstdomain.some/$ http://seconddomain.some/ [L,R=301]
```

With no query, it works, else it gives 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^page.php.*$    http://seconddomain.some/etc/ [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Make sure `/etc/` exists or you will get a 404